# Shorter / Faster method in Sprite kit

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

Im trying to find a faster way to check for multiple integers. This works but will be massive.   Im new and teaching myself ObjC, any help would be great.

```
if ([_scoreLabel.text intValue]== 2||
[_scoreLabel.text intValue]==17||
[_scoreLabel.text intValue]==33||
[_scoreLabel.text intValue]==42 ||
[_scoreLabel.text intValue]==52||
[_scoreLabel.text intValue]==65 ||
[_scoreLabel.text intValue]==85 ||
[_scoreLabel.text intValue]==101 ||
[_scoreLabel.text intValue]==125 ||
[_scoreLabel.text intValue]==139)
{
[self setupNode];
}
```

Comment: Is there some pattern here. What problem is this code intended to solve?

Comment: No Pattern.   Just want to shorten this up.  Id like to have up to 1000 or so integers in a string but everything I've tried gives errors.

Comment: What makes these numbers special?

Comment: Nothing special.  Im just running actions when the player hits a specific score.

Comment: It won't improve performance but you could keep the numbers in an array and then check if scoreLabel.text is in it.

Comment: @Bryan Chen's answer is exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to shorten your code is to place the numbers into an array and then compare each array element against the score in a loop. Here's an example of how to do that:

Create and initialize an NSArray. Each element of the array is an NSNumber.

```
NSArray *array = @[@2, @17, @33, @42, @52, @65, @85, @101, @125, @139];
```

Compare each element of the array against the score in a loop. Exit the loop if a match is found.

```
for (NSNumber *number in array) {
    if ([_scoreLabel.text intValue] == number.intValue) {
        [self setupNode];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

improvement over @0x141E's answer

```
NSArray *array = @[@2, @17, @33, @42, @52, @65, @85, @101, @125, @139];
if ([array containsObject:@(_scoreLabel.text intValue)]) {
    [self setupNode];
}
```